# SonarLint warning, this code will always return the same value

Tags: java-8, option-type, sonarlint

SonarLint is telling me:

```
"Refactor this code to not always return the same value."
```

But I don't seem to understand why

```
private List<InvoiceRejectionMessage> invoiceList = new ArrayList<>();

public String getMessage() {
    if(!invoiceList.isEmpty()) {
        return invoiceList
                .stream()
                .max(comparing(InvoiceRejectionMessage::getCreatedAt))
                .get()
                .getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

InvoiceList is defined and will always be initialized, so it can't be null only empty. If it's empty, return null. If it's not, we're certain there's an element in there that can be returned by .max() and .get()

I don't feel comfortable refactoring this method just because Sonarlint tells me to, I'd rather know why I'm getting this warning

Comment: `invoiceList` is initialized, but it is an empty array. You never `.Add()` something to it. Therefore the `.isEmpty()` will return `true` and your function will return `null`.

Comment: @RonNabuurs Does it check the rest of the codebase for an .add()?

Comment: If I copy paste the snippet in a test project in my Intellij with Sonarlint I don't get an error even though I don't call `.Add()`. Maybe it's an setting somewhere. I'm afraid I don't know it either otherwise.

Comment: Stylistic question: why return not return `Optional<String>` rather than a "nullable" `String`?

Comment: @Jubobs Currently its only use is in a DTO which I'd rather keep clean; e.g. dto.setInvoiceMessage(invoice.getMessage)

Comment: @Ron Nabuurs, that's weird as we don't really have a special profile running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule associated to this hint is

> squid:S3516 - Methods returns should not be invariant

The SonarQube implementation of this rule is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/se/checks/InvariantReturnCheck.java).

Without seeing your code as a whole, I'm not 100% sure why this rule gets triggered. However, I suspect that Sonar is able to figure out that

1. `invoiceList` is unconditionally empty and; therefore
2. the `if` branch of your if-then-else statement never gets exercised; therefore,
3. `the getMessage` method unconditionally returns `null`.

---

Anyway, there is no need to treat the empty list as a special case; you can simplify the code in the following way, which will likely pacify Sonar:

```
private List<InvoiceRejectionMessage> invoiceList = new ArrayList<>();

public String getMessage() {
    return invoiceList
            .stream()
            .max(comparing(InvoiceRejectionMessage::getCreatedAt))
            .map(InvoiceRejectionMessage::getMessage)
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Incidentally, if you can change the class's API, its clients would benefit from changing `getMessage`'s return type to `Optional<String>` (simply drop the last `orElse(null)` call):

```
public Optional<String> getMessage() {
    return invoiceList
            .stream()
            .max(comparing(InvoiceRejectionMessage::getCreatedAt))
            .map(InvoiceRejectionMessage::getMessage)
}
```

Comment: This indeed pacified sonar and it looks cleaner. Still I'd like to know why Sonar thinks it's 'wrong'

Comment: Sorry should've mentioned this: squid:S3516 combined with squid:S3655 (it wants me to call isPresent before the .get() which I understand but it useless since it won't be null or empty when we reach the statement). MIght be that the combination of the 2 causes Sonar to think it's worse than it is?

Comment: @Laurens I've augmented my answer. And even Sonar is right to point out that `Optional#get` requires care, [the `isPresent`-`get` idiom is considered bad practice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14&t=10m30s); in fact, it can be avoided here.

Comment: You don't specifically solve my question but your answer is concise and well put together, I'll mark this as solved and chalk it up to a hiccup from Sonarlint